# Modify a ground truth image (GeoTIFF file) using QGIS/Python

Tags: qgis, python

As part of my masters thesis, I am replicating an original research paper that uses deep learning to create a map of changes in forest cover over a period of several years. This was done using Landsat8 images combined with vegetation indices (NDVI for instance).

The original research paper used geo-referenced PDF land cover maps of the regions being analysed (15 specific districts in Pakistan). In discussion with a professor at my university, I realised that I don't need to go through the same tedious process that the original authors did, since the land cover data for the country I wanted to analyse (The Netherlands) was widely available, albeit for only a select few years. I downloaded the `gpkg` files [from here (the site is in Dutch only)](https://service.pdok.nl/cbs/bestandbodemgebruik/2015/atom/index.xml). I created a new `gpkg` file that contains **only** the `forest` class from the original `gpkg` file. This is where my problems begin.

I have tried everything I know (and a lot of tutorials I found online) to try and convert the "forest class" `gpkg` file into a raster file that could serve as my ground truth image. The original research paper created a `GeoTIFF` file (after geo-referencing) that had 3 unique values - [0 1 2]. 2 is `forest` class, 1 is `non-forest` class, and 0 is `NULL` class (NULL = all pixels that lie outside the boundary of that region). Sample ground truth image (used in the original paper) shown below: [image: OG ground truth]

The most I have been able to come up with is a `GeoTIFF` file that has 2 unique values [0 1], looking something like this:

[image: my ground truth]

How do I convert the `gpkg` file containing the `forest` labels to a 'GeoTIFF' file similar to the **first** image shown above? I've tried the `vector to raster` option in QGIS, but it doesn't work properly. Since the "code" (like an ID number) for the `forest` class in the `gpkg` file is 60, the resulting file contains only 0 and 60 as distinct values. This is not ideal for me since the code for the original research paper explicitly assigns 0, 1, and 2 as the final values for the ground truth image, and I need to stick to the OG paper as much as possible.

Comment: Ummm, sorry, but I am really struggling to follow what you're saying. Do I have to use QGIS?

Comment: You don't *have* to use QGIS, but since you tagged & mentioned QGIS in your question, my comment is written to apply to QGIS and gives you a starting point and terminology to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new column to the original landuse layer.
2. Use the field calculator to set the value of the new column to 1.
   This will apply to all records/polygons.
3. Then use the select by attributes tool to select just the forest
   polygons,
4. Use the field calculator to set the value of the new
   column to 2. This will apply to just the forest records.
5. Rasterize the layer using the new column as the attribute to burn in

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked!

Comment: I have accepted the answer you provided, thank you! I do not have enough reputation to vote, but I did click the upvote button and received a message saying my feedback was recorded.